# Is there a limit on remembered Wi-Fi networks?

Tags: ios, network, wifi

Is there a limit to the number of Wi-Fi networks I can save on my iPhone?

I travel a lot for work and want to save the Wi-Fi networks from all of those locations (over 100), so it automatically connects when I'm there.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no limit to the number of WI-Fi networks your computer can remember unless your computer runs out of memory because it has to remember too many networks. ;)